# How to set a Windows Form size to maximum if the last Form's size is on maximum

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm working on an app that contains two windows form:

- [The first from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRVyG.jpg)
- [The second form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wzC9.jpg)

I want that if user change the size of first form to maximum size that contains all desktop . the next form when loaded, it's size change to maximum .

I wrote this but not worked:

```
Private Sub sc(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged
    If Me.Size = New Size(MaximumSize) Then
        MainMenu.Size = New Size(MaximumSize)
    End If
End Sub
```

I'd be happy if you can help me.

Comment: is my code correct ?

Comment: Your form looks good and you can make it better by removing empty spaces at the right side of window. Also if you put the menu at right side, it makes more sense in a right to left form. – But your code is not correct. see the answer below.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks but I found better answer and put it here .. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `WindowState` of your new form to `WindowState` of your current form, before show.

Also when the form is not maximized, if you want to show the next form exactly with size and location of your first form, you can also set the `Size` and `Location` of your new form:

```
'I suppose this is the button on the first form that opens the second form 
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'I Suppose Form2 is your new Form
    Dim f As New Form2()
    f.WindowState = Me.WindowState
    f.Location = Me.Location
    f.Size = Me.Size
    f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    f.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this code in the form2_load part and worked

```
   Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Maximize form size if the past form size is maximized 
    If Form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End If
```

Comment: No problem, It works too. but when you got more experienced you will see the other answer is better :) It supports also being the same size. Also it is a very bad idea to refer `Form1` this way. It's good to answer you own question, but not in the case when there is a more complete and better answer.